# how to make Google OAuth honor btmpl=mobile?

Tags: android, oauth, android-emulator, google-api

What I'm referring to is a documented bug: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=58c4f7fbe60be52c&hl=en. Basically, when I use an older Android emulator or device, I do get a mobile-sized page for authorization: [image: auth page with readable text], whereas with a level 8 (Android 2.2) emulator, it shows an unreadable page: [image: cannot read what this is saying].

Has anyone found a fix for this? All I know is to add btmpl=mobile to the authentication query during the OAuth process, and apparently that's not enough. The login (authentication) page shows up fine, mobile-style, on both old and new emulators and devices; it's just the authorization page that's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it. It just started working. Not when using signpost, but with my own OAuth code the authorization page shows up fine: [image: new results are what I wanted]

Sqeaky wheel gets the grease. Thanks Google!